# How to split audio and video from .mp4 in c++ (most efficient way)

Tags: c++, video, mp4, audio-streaming

I need to split the audio and the video of a given .mp4 video file.So for that I need to do it in c++ language as well.Another thing is that way should be efficient as well. Wishing your help. Thanks.